# Adding multiple user to a group in linux at once

Tags: linux, command-line

Please help me in this.
I have users as["Aarmy1, army2, to.. army 50.] & ["navy1, navy2,.. navy50].
How to add above two class in group "Army" and "Navy" respectively in linux.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple for loop as below :

Army:

```
for user in army{1..50}; do usermod -aG Army $user; done
```

Navy:

```
for user in navy{1..50}; do usermod -aG Navy $user; done
```

OR

You can even do both at once like below :

```
for i in {1..50}; do usermod -aG Army army$i; usermod -aG Navy navy$i; done
```

Comment: to add a user to a group the option `-aG` should be used like `usermod -aG groupname username`

Comment: @binarysta : Yes , it is to append.Updated.Thanks for notifying me!!!

Comment: thanks a lot for your kind answer

Comment: @GouravSingh  :  np ...have a great day...